# Social media icon did not appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make icons buttons in the footer section, and for some reason the social media icon did not appear.
I used the `<link>` tag in the head section but this doesn't work:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class=" row text-center padding ">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-12 social padding ">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-fb" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-tw" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-gplus" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-ins" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-yt" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-whatsapp" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>

    </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light" style="border-top: 2px solid #222222;
  width:1000px;
  margin-top: .3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;">
        <h5>&copy;2020 Copyright </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: `class="fa fa-facebook-f"` etc, not `fab`

Answer (score 0):

Just include the kit. Add `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/13ccb33514.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` to the beginning of your document instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`.
Here is your code:

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/13ccb33514.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class=" row text-center padding ">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-12 social padding ">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-fb" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-tw" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-gplus" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-ins" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-yt" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-whatsapp" type="button" role="button"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>

    </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light" style="border-top: 2px solid #222222;
  width:1000px;
  margin-top: .3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;">
        <h5>&copy;2020 Copyright </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/zYvdWqa?editors=1000

Comment: if you use the "kit", do you need the css? since the "kit" loads css?

Answer (score -1):

How about plain CSS and JS ?: 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4mroec5/1/)

```
<a class="btn-fb"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg/300px-Facebook_icon_2013.svg.png"</a>

img {
  width: 10%;
}

document.querySelector('.btn-fb').onclick = () => {
window.location.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook,_Inc.";
}
```